# Very difficult .htaccess -> nginx rewrite conversion for CakePHP + front controller

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

Using Apache, the following .htaccess file was placed in the root folder - */digital/* - of a CakePHP application.

[NB: above this directory, at true root, there was a non-Cake PHP application with a different .htaccess profile.]

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/digital/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /digital
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This file forwarded every request URI **after** */digital/* back to the front controller, as a GET variable (i.e. "?url=x").

For example, navigating to:

**"www.mywebsite.com/digital/admin/login/"**

became:

**"www.mywebsite.com/digital/index.php?url=/digital/admin/login/".**

Every attempt I've made results in a redirect loop or failure.

How can I make this work in nginx? Especially without creating a separate virtual host?

Edit - my config:

```
  location /digital/ {
  try_files   $uri $uri/ index.php?url=$uri&$args;
  }
```

Comment: Show us your config.

Comment: Which part specifically?

Comment: I've edited with the relevant block. thanks!

Comment: I'd hazard a guess of `try_files   $uri $uri/ /digital/ index.php?url=$uri&$args;` - the [try_files directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) example has an absolute path prefixed with the folder in the location block.